# Labeling x axis on qicharts

Tags: charts, controls, axis, labeling

I have produced the Individuals control chart depicted below. The data set has a variable named date that is in R format YMD. I would like to have the x axis display each YMD with a label identifying the specific YMD.

Here is my current code to produce the individuals control chart: qic(data$records, chart=c("i"), x.format="%Y-%m-%d").

[Individuals Control Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytVIU.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the x and xlab arguments. Here's an example using the updated qicharts2 package:

```
library(qicharts2)

# Build data frame for example
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:24, 4),
             ReportMonth = (rep(seq(as.Date('2014-1-1'),
                                    length.out = 24,
                                    by = 'month'),
                                4)),
             num = rbinom(4 * 24, 100, 0.5),
             denom = round(runif(4 * 24, 90, 110)),
             grp1 = rep(c('g', 'h'), each = 48),
             grp2 = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 24))

#now plot an 'i' chart :
  qic(
  x= ReportMonth,
  y= num,
  # n= denom,
  data=df, 
  chart= "i",
  x.format="%Y-%m-%d",
  x.angle = 90,
  y.expand = 40, # where to start y axis from
  xlab = "Month",
  ylab= "Value")
```

Output:

[image: i chart]